# Is Lipschitz space finite dimensional?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, compactness, lipschitz-functions, arzela-ascoli

Let $X=C([a,b])$ equipped with the norm $\Vert.\Vert_{\infty}$. The closed subspace $F$ of $\alpha$-Holder continuous ($0\lt\alpha\le1)$ functions $F\subset X$ is finite dimensional because if I take a closed unit ball in it, the ball is compact (using Ascoli-Arzelà). What can we say about Lipschitz continuous functions space? Can we argue this way and conclude that it is finite dimensional?

Comment: I think the same proof should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your argument in the case $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is not true. Arzela-Ascoli asserts that the ball
$$
\{ f | \|f\|_{0,\alpha} \le 1\},
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_{0,\alpha}$ denotes the Hölder norm,
is compact in the space
$(C([a,b]), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$.
It does **not** implies  compactness in the Hölder space
$(C^{0,\alpha}([a,b]), \|\cdot\|_{0,\alpha})$!

In fact, $C^{0,\alpha}([a,b])$ is infinite dimensional and, thus, cannot have a compact unit ball.

Answer (score 4):

$1,x,x^{2}/2,x^{3}/3,...$ are linearly independent elements of this space when $a=0$ and $b=1$.

For equicontinuity you need a condition like $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M|x-y|$ for all $f$ in $F$ with $M$ independent of $f$. Since such a  condition is not available your argument fails. For no value of $\alpha$ is your space finite dimensional.

PS: linear independence of the sequence I have defined is obvious since no non-zero polynomial can have infinitely many zeros.

Comment: Why the proof doesn't work with $\alpha=1$? technically for $\alpha$ in that range Lipschitz functions are a subspace of $\alpha$-Holder continuous functions

Comment: Equicontinuity is not true. You are considering functions with sup norm bounded by 1 but the constant in Lipschitz condition is not bounded.

Answer (score 3):

No.  $\{x\mapsto \lvert x-y\rvert: y\in(a,b)\}$ are linearly independent 1-Lipschitz functions in $C([a,b])$.

Comment: Why the proof doesn't work with α=1? technically for α in that range Lipschitz functions are a subspace of α-Holder continuous functions